# how to use the instanceof operator to check parameter type in props data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

in vue guide doc, I have looked at the documentation about prop validation :

> The type can be one of the following native constructors:
>
> String
>
> Number
>
> Boolean
>
> Function
>
> Object
>
> Array
>
> In addition, type can also be a custom constructor function and the assertion will be made with an instanceof check.

so, how can I use the instanceof operator to achieve parameter custom type checking ?

Comment: I got your question: there is an example in the docs (https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html) and vue is using `instanceof` internally (https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/util/props.js#L146). I am also curious to understand what it does exactly

Comment: Did you get an answer on this?  I'd like to do a custom validation on a prop that could be String or Array but haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use custom type like:

```
props: {
  file: { type: File, required: true }
}
```